# php not grabbing zip code from freegeoip.net

Tags: php, geo

The script I have works so far to pull the ip, lat, and long. The zip code isn't being pulled off. I can't figure out what is broken and what it needs to make it work. Any ideas?

```
// Function to get the client ip address
function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}

$ipaddress = getUserIP();

$geoIP  = 
json_decode(file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/$ipaddress"), true);

$lat = $geoIP['latitude'];
$lon = $geoIP['longitude'];
$zip = $geoIP['zip'];
```

Comment: For the record, the freegeoip API will be fully discontinued July 1st this year according to the announcement: https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip#readme

Comment: General tip: be _very_ careful with PHP's "shut up" operator `@`. You could be suppressing important output, especially in development.

Comment: Thanks @Chris .. I removed those and didn't remember seeing them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old freegeoip has been depreciated and the new service ipstack offers free api access. Below is a simple curl call that will get the info you want (and a lot more).

```
$url = 'http://api.ipstack.com/134.201.250.155?access_key=YOURKEY';  
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   

$output = curl_exec($ch);  

$api_result = json_decode($output, true); 

$lat = $api_result['latitude']; 
$lon = $api_result['longitude']; 
$zip = $api_result['zip'];

echo $zip;
echo $lat;
echo $lon;
```

Comment: @Zack Abrams I have added this new code with the new API but I  am having trouble getting it to work.  `// Initialize CURL:
  $ch = curl_init('https://api.ipstack.com/'.$ipaddress.'?access_key='.$access_key.'');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 // Store the data:
  $json = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

 // Decode JSON response:
  $api_result = json_decode($json, true);

 // Output the "capital" object inside "location"
  $lat = $api_result['location']['latitude'];
  $lon = $api_result['location']['longitude'];
  $zip = $api_result['location']['zip'];`

Comment: the lat , lon and zip vars are not in the location index. try this:

Comment: $url = 'http://api.ipstack.com/134.201.250.155?access_key=YOURKEY';  
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   

$output = curl_exec($ch);  

$api_result = json_decode($output, true); 

$lat = $api_result['latitude']; 
$lon = $api_result['longitude']; 
$zip = $api_result['zip'];

echo $zip;

Comment: I changed it where the `$lat = $api_result['latitude']; $lon = $api_result['longitude']; $zip = $api_result['zip'];` would be set but it's still not echoing or returning the variables.

Comment: The curl options in my first answer will not return the data to be saved as a variable. Use the curl calls from the comment (I will also update the answer to reflect this)

Comment: You had it right the first time. I deleted my old data and used your code and it worked!! Thanks bud..